# Text tagging / Classification for automation

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I had an opportunity to automate and use ML to free up my time
In DevOps jerkin automation , I need to standardize the stage name , but with 2000 + project in enterprise some stage name are automatically framed based name of the project,repository name which may not follow the standards. There is a report which pulls all these unclassified new Pipe-line stage name and using pattern matching , manually classify them into different buckets.
When I try to use sci kit most of algorithms not accepting string as input.
Anyone in this group to point right algorithms and samples to use

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem in Machine Learning and a lot of algorithms assume that you have change your categorical columns into numerical ones.

First, you can use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) that will

> Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.

This method will transform your strings into integers.

Then, you need to think if this method is relevant. Often it is not, because there will be a hierarchy between your different words and the algorithms may think that word 5 is greater than word 4 (which is not).

You can use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) (after using LabelEncoder because OneHotEncoder encode numerical columns).

> This creates a binary column for each category and returns a sparse matrix or dense array.

Be aware that OneHotEncoder will multiply the number of features which can be a problem to train your models.

You can also use [get_dummies from pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) instead of LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder. See this [article](https://medium.com/@guaisang/handling-categorical-features-get-dummies-onehotencoder-and-multicollinearity-f9d473a40417) that compares the two approches.

A lot of NLP algorithms also use a "[bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)" model. Have a look to [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) library that may help you to solve your problem.